# Execute the dict string without eval in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, eval

I have dict and that needs to make the dict values executable.
it's possible through "eval"

Ex:

```
FROMDATE=22061988
data = {'param':"f'sometext({FROMDATE})'"}
eval(data['param']) 

'sometext(22061988)'
```

But I want to achieve the same output without using the module **"eval"**.

If we could remove the double quotes around the dict value so that it will be executable but can't achieve it through the "replace" or "strip()" modules.

```
>>> data['param'].replace('"', '')
"f'sometext({FROMDATE})'"


>>> data['param'].strip('"')
"f'sometext({FROMDATE})'"
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? What would you like the value in the dictionary to be?

Comment: I want to get it printed output without "eval" function